# Chi square kernel function: which version?

Tags: machine-learning, chi-squared-test, kernel-trick

I was reading [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5459466&tag=1) paper about Kernenlized locality-sensitive hashing (LSH) and in section 6.4 the chi-square-kernel function to measure the distance between two histograms `hi` and `hj` as:

[image]

Anyway in [this](http://crsouza.com/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning-applications/#chisquare) link is defined in section 20 as:

[image]

And then as:

[image]

**Which one should I use for measuring the distance between two image histograms obtained from a Bag of Features?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two histograms using Chi-Square distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184101/comparing-two-histograms-using-chi-square-distance)