# How to determine the similarity between histograms

Tags: goodness-of-fit, histogram

The questions is asked at [How to assess the similarity of two histograms?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/how-to-assess-the-similarity-of-two-histograms)

However, I'm not sure if it's the same question as mine, so I'd like to ask again.

---

I have a dataset, which covers a long time span. So it is possible that in some years, the data are corrupted. For example, I plot the histogram by 5 years:

[image]

Look at the right plots, it is apparent that the distribution of the last one is very different from the above.

But how can I qualify this difference, and be able to determine it by code?

I know in [How to assess the similarity of two histograms?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/how-to-assess-the-similarity-of-two-histograms), the answer is 2 sample gof test, but is it proper for my case? I have several plots to compare at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the questions you want to tackle. If you are concerned with similarity, you may use the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), that is, you normalize the histograms, and calculate its scalar product which gives you a measure of how aligned those histograms are.

But if you rather want to see if two histograms are significantly different, you may use the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test, as pointed out in the answer you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this are through a [QQ plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) & a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test.

Since you are looking for a programatic way to determine and quanitfy the difference of two distributions, i'd recommend a KS test. A KS test is nice in that you can easily get a p-value out of the test and it is very easy to run. Here's the example python code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

x = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
y = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)

ks_2samp(x, y)
(0.022999999999999909, 0.95189016804849658)
# p-value = .95 (no significant difference)
```

Comment: But which one should I  use as a standard? There are several plots to compare in this case. Maybe I should make a score matrix?